# DMARC RUA reports - who sends them?

Tags: dmarc

As in the topic; which server exactly sends RUA reports to other servers? I am a DMARC user and receive a lot of reports every day. However, nobody has ever received reports from me!

Do I set it up on my own? If yes, are there any ready-to-go scripts I could use so I would not need to 'reinvent the wheel' so to speak? If no, what format should I stick to as far as creating them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Receiving email servers are responsible for generating DMARC aggregate (RUA) reports.  So the key question is the following - are you running your own email servers (Postfix, Exchange, etc.) or are you using a service to manage the inboxes for your domain (Google Apps, Office 365)?

If you are using a service, then that service will manage generating DMARC reports.  Some services (Google Apps, Office 365) do this out of the box, while some others have not implemented DMARC receiver functionality.

If you are running your own system, then you'll need to add DMARC reporting functionality.  The [OpenDmarc project](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/) provides a plug-in to provide that functionality for Postfix and Sendmail systems.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for!! Strange that this topic is usually omitted when talking about DMARC. Many pages provide info about DMARC but not too many of them say how you configure your infrastructure in order to send aggregated reports. Cheers Peter!